# I having problems doing a slider in CSS in this web

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I'm doing a web for a client, and he asked me to make him a slider in the main section.

I have seen many ways to do slider, but the problem is that I have built the web with a template, and I do not get the proper way to do it. The section have the image in a background-image Css property, I think the correct way is slide the , but I have tried 1000 things and I am going crazy.

This is the "div" that I have to slide in 3 parts:

```css
/* Banner */

 #banner {
  /*background-image: url("../../images/FullSizeRender.jpg");*/
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 28em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
 }

  #banner header {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background: #212121;
   background: rgba(27, 27, 27, 0.75);
   color: #fff;
   padding: 1.5em 0;
  }

  /* ... More code not encessary in this question*/
```

```html
<!-- Banner -->

    <section id="banner">
     <header>
      <h2>Reconocido por: <em>Afiliación oficial con la tabacalera <a href="http://html5up.net">Monte Castillo</a></em></h2>
      <a href="quienessomos.html" class="button">Leer más</a>
     </header>
    </section>
                <!--2 More sections to slide-->
```

If you can put me the correct CSS code to make the slider, or if you find an other way like jQuery or Javascript, I will thank you very much. The reason i choose CSS to do it is because I'm afraid that the template code will be altered, I do not just master javascript / jQuery, and if I break something out of CSS I can repair it.

This is the domain I host the tests I do: http://martinherrada.com. 
Thanks for your attemption

Cordially,
MH11 Eleven

Comment: Can you explain how this slider should work? As in is the slider supposed to slide to the left with 3 divs total? For example, does it show div 1, then div 2, then div 2?

Comment: yes, exactly. in 6 or 7 seconds second slide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS animations to achieve the slider effect with background image property.

Comment: I know it. But the question is how?
You know what is the correct way? What would you add in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Bootstrap carousel:

`http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel`

A tutorial on w3schools:

`https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp`

It is quite easy to implement.

Comment: Thank you bro, i take a look (Y)